# How to assign a JQuery selector to a variable

Tags: jquery

What is the way to assign a selector to a variable and reuse that variable to access the first value?

```
var items = $("ul li");
var firstItem = items[0];
alert(firstItem.html()); <-- error
```

Alternatively,

```
var firstItem = $("ul li:first");
```

can be used to get the first item but what if I do this first in case I need to use the list for something else later:

```
var items = $("ul li");
(what statement should I use here to use the ":first" function with my "items" variable?)
```

Comment: What you're after is [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) ~ `var firstItem = items.eq(0)`. When you use array access like `items[0]`, the result is an `HTMLElement`, not a jQuery object

Comment: When you use: items[0]; you get a html element, not a jquery variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `items.first()` instead. See [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/)'s documentation.

Every `:selector` usually has an equivalent as a function.